# Rate app option is called when clicking all three buttons, how do I call it only for the assigned button in android studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have three options in my app where a user can either, rate my app, share the app or visit the privacy policy page. However when I added the rate app section code to my app it opens up the same window when clicking all three buttons. How do I fix this so that the rate my app only opens up to the rate app button only and not for all three buttons?

This is the current code that I have for all three options in my app using android studio. This code is located in my MainActivity.java class.

```
  @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_policy:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.example.com"));
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_share:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sharing URL");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mydomain.tapp");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
    try {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + this.getPackageName())));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + this.getPackageName())));
    }
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;

}
```

And this is the segment which I added which should carry out the function of rate my app by sending the user to the rate app section of my app.

```
try {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + this.getPackageName())));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + this.getPackageName())));
    }
```

Also my navigation menu code in xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_share"
        android:title="Share App"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_share">
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_thumb"
        android:title="Rate App"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_thumb">
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_policy"
        android:title="Privacy Policy"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_lock">
    </item>
</group>
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Can you change your code of `onNavigationItemSelected` function like mentioned below

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_policy:
            Intent policyIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.example.com"));
            startActivity(policyIntent);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_share:
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sharing URL");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mydomain.tapp");
            startActivity(shareIntent);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_thumb:
            try {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + this.getPackageName())));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + this.getPackageName())));
            }
            break;
    }
    
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;

}
```

Comment: there's an error in your code can you fix it: Variable 'intent' is already defined in the scope

Comment: i have updated code .. can you please check @Marfog509